# how can I compare between two ggplots in R studio in layers ( in other words having two plots over each other and compare them through my inputs )?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, shiny, magrittr

I have two output plots and I want to get them **above each other**, so I can compare between them through the **selected inputs**   `input$sel` and `input$sel2`.

I mean with **above each other** is one should be in the background and the other one should be another **layer** on it transparent, so one can see both plots at the same time.

If data are necessary,  here is data.csv file :
https://impfdashboard.de/static/data/germany_vaccinations_by_state.tsv

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

#Summarize Data and then Plot 
data <- reactive({
req(input$sel)
df <- germany_vaccinations_k %>%  group_by(code) %>% summarise( output = get(input$sel))
print(df)
})

data2 <- reactive({
req(input$sel2)
df <- germany_vaccinations_k %>%  group_by(code) %>% summarise( output = get(input$sel2))
print(df)
})

#Plot 1
output$plot <- renderPlot({  
g <- ggplot( data(), aes( y = output   ,x = code ,ho = factor(code) )  ) 
g + geom_bar( stat = "sum" )

output$plot2 <- renderPlot({  
g <- ggplot( data(), aes( y = output   ,x = code ,ho = factor(code) )  ) 
g + geom_bar( stat = "sum" )
})
```

```
ui <- basicPage(   
#first-input
selectInput(inputId = "sel",  label = "Möglichkeit auswählen",
list("vaccinationsTotal","peopleFirstTotal","peopleFullTotal","peopleBoosterTotal")),

#second-input
selectInput(inputId = "sel2",  label = "Möglichkeit auswählen",
list("vaccinationsTotal","peopleFirstTotal","peopleFullTotal","peopleBoosterTotal")),

#the both outputs 
plotOutput("plot")
plotOutput("plot2")
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can combine both plots and play around with `alpha` argument. I added two sliders that enables the user to control the level of transparency of both plots.

```
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot() +
      geom_bar(data = data(), aes(y = output, x = code), stat = "sum", alpha = .5) +
      geom_bar(data = data2(), aes(y = output, x = code), stat = "sum", alpha = .5, fill = "lightblue")
  })
```

app:

```
germany_vaccinations_k <- read_tsv("germany_vaccinations_by_state.tsv")

ui <- basicPage(
  # first-input
  selectInput(
    inputId = "sel", label = "Möglichkeit auswählen",
    list("vaccinationsTotal", "peopleFirstTotal", "peopleFullTotal", "peopleBoosterTotal")
  ),

  # second-input
  selectInput(
    inputId = "sel2", label = "Möglichkeit auswählen",
    list("vaccinationsTotal", "peopleFirstTotal", "peopleFullTotal", "peopleBoosterTotal")
  ),
  sliderInput("alpha_sel", "Select First Alpha", min = .01, max = 1, value = 0.5),
  sliderInput("alpha_sel2", "Select Second Alpha", min = .01, max = 1, value = 0.8),


  # the both outputs
  plotOutput("plot")
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Summarize Data and then Plot
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$sel)
    df <- germany_vaccinations_k %>%
      group_by(code) %>%
      summarise(output = get(input$sel))
    print(df)
  })

  data2 <- reactive({
    req(input$sel2)
    df <- germany_vaccinations_k %>%
      group_by(code) %>%
      summarise(output = get(input$sel2))
    print(df)
  })


  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot() +
      geom_bar(data = data(), aes(y = output, x = code), stat = "sum", alpha = input$alpha_sel) +
      geom_bar(data = data2(), aes(y = output, x = code), stat = "sum", alpha = input$alpha_sel2, fill = "lightblue")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts, the answer is exactly what I was searching for, even with extra functionalities.